# Auto Completion is not showing in Android Studio on MacOS

Tags: flutter, macos, android-studio, dart

When I press Command + Space it shows "No suggestions", even if the Power Save Mode is disabled you can see the following screenshots.
[image: here is screenshot]

how can I fix this?

I want code completion to be enabled.

Comment: Command + Space is assigned to spotlight search. You may try Command + I

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It's probably that Command + Space is assigned to a different keyboard shortcut instead (Spotlight search).

I solved the issue by assigning Option + Space to the code completion instead of Command + Space. To do this, you can Open:

*Android studio preferences -> Keymap, type in "Baisc" -> click on Code completion -> add keyboard shortcut.*

[image]

Comment: after these changes it still give me "No Suggesstions" i dont know why but did not work i still searching about this but did not see any solid solution. :(

Comment: the issue solved by the version of android studio, when I uninstall the latest version of android studio which is giraffe version and install one version down, it start works, i think the auto completion is deprecated or removed from the giraffe version or not so.